# Why am I seeing large variances for the question count for a tag?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-synonyms, question-count

Yesterday the REST tag showed a question count of around 1750.

Today if you go here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest you see 2027 questions.

However, if you go to tags https://stackoverflow.com/tags and search for Rest you see 2253

If I check other tags I do see small discrepancies between the numbers, but 200 questions seem like a whole lot.  Could this have something to do with the synonyms?  REST has a synonym RESTful and there are approx 200 questions with tags that start with "Restful".

Answer (score 2):

This almost definitely has to do with 2 things:

- Restful tag synonym
- Caching the count of questions tagged **`[x]`**

The count of questions tagged **`[x]`** is heavily cached, and the questions tagged **`[restful]`** were probably mass-retagged to **`[rest]`**.